# Save random integer into form of Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am trying to save po_id as a unique key of the "Order table". So I am generating a random number in the Order Form. But the issue is that somehow I can not save the form, even though all the fields are filled up.

models.py

```
def random_string():
    return str(random.randint(10000, 99999))

class Order(models.Model):
    po_id = models.CharField(max_length=4, default = random_string)
    supplier = models.ForeignKey(Supplier, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

forms.py

```
class OrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['supplier', 'product', 'po_id']

        widgets = {
            'supplier': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'supplier'}),
            'product': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'product'}),
            
        }
```

views.py

```
def create_order(request):
    from django import forms
    form = OrderForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        forms = OrderForm(request.POST)
        if forms.is_valid():
            po_id = forms.cleaned_data['po_id']
            supplier = forms.cleaned_data['supplier']
            product = forms.cleaned_data['product']
           
            order = Order.objects.create(
                po_id=po_id,
                supplier=supplier,
                product=product,
            )
            return redirect('order-list')
    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'store/addOrder.html', context)
```

Order.html

```
<form action="#" method="post"  novalidate="novalidate">
                            {% csrf_token %}

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="po_id" class="control-label mb-1">ID</label>
                                {{ form.po_id }}
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="supplier" class="control-label mb-1">Supplier</label>
                                {{ form.supplier }}
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="product" class="control-label mb-1">Product</label>
                                {{ form.product }}
                            </div>
                                                          
                            <div>
                                <button id="payment-button" type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block">
                                    <span id="payment-button-amount">Save</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
```

Can help me with how I can solve the issue?

Comment: your `random_string` method is creating random int with length 5, but the `max_length` of your `po_id` is 4, also show your html form please.

Comment: if you are creating `po_id` automatically you don't need to add it in your form fields. remove it from your form fields and after `forms.is_valid()` generate it automatically and pass it to your order as your `po_id`.

Comment: @MojixCoder thanks for the help it works. Also FYI, I have added order HTML form

Comment: and if you want to make sure that your `po_id` is unique and you are using it as your `Primary Key`, use `AutoField` or `UUIDField` or `BigAutoField`. it's better to use them instead of your random `CharField`

Comment: Why dont you use `PrimaryKey` ? It will be generated when you save in the database, and will be unique